# Сериализация в java

Tags: java

Не могу разобраться с сериализацией, имеется объект у которого есть поле меняющееся через сеттер, отправляю через сокет по сети клиенту, клиент получает обьект и видит значение в поле, далее меняю поле в объекте снова отправляю, клиент получает вот только поле не меняется, остается старое значение.

```
отправка
unit.setX(20);
while(true){
    userList.get(0).sendData(unit);//отправляем 20
    unit.setX(200);//меняем на 200
}

прием
while(true){
   unit = (Unit) network.receiveData();
   unit.getX //значение остается 20. 
}
```

отправка и прием в цикле.

Сериализуемый класс:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
class Unit implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }


}
```

стрим:

```
public Object receiveData() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    return recievObject.readObject();

}

class Network
public void sendData(Unit unit) throws IOException{

    sendObject.writeObject(unit);
    sendObject.flush();


}
```

Тк завалили кучей советов и ответов, меняю постановку вопроса как организовывается робота с сетью ,  или посоветуйте хорошую книгу в этом направление.

Comment: Диагностировать проблему без подробностей (в виде кода) о сериализуемом классе нельзя.

Comment: http://www.ccfit.nsu.ru/~deviv/courses/oop/java_ser_rus.html советую всем кто столкнется с данной проблемой.

Answer (score 2):

```
отправка
userList.get(0).sendData(unit);
unit.setX(200);
```

отправил

поменял

нечего не смущает?

Comment: цикл, отправил 20 поменял на 200, отправил, у клиента все равно 20.Дополнил.

Comment: так ты же 20 отправляешь - 20 принимаешь, все правильно

Comment: да это правильно, может я туплю,в первом цикле объект unit отправляется с x=20,на втором цикле x=200 и тоже отправляется, у клиента unit x=20 и не меняется. Может я не понимаю как оно работает.

Comment: проблему понял, но сказать всеравно что то сложно, ты это тестируешь на одном компе? не понятно как ты проверяешь это? может ты смотришь в первый объект? может должно идет 2й? может где-то подменяешь ссылку на unit...

Comment: Упростил код до "3 строк" тож самое, машина одна.

Comment: попробуй без циклов...

Comment: Прокатило путем создания нового экземпляра Unit тогда у клиента x меняется